# Hibernate LockMode release and fail-fast if the lock cannot be acquired

Tags: java, hibernate, transactions, locking, pessimistic-locking

I have two questions regarding the Pessimistic LockModes that are available in Hibernate 3.3.2.ga :

1. If I lock a set of rows using lockmode UPGRADE, do the locks gets released when you move out of the transaction scope? If yes, can we lock-unlock across transactions?
2. For the following scenario, which LockMode would be useful

   - Thread 1, tries to obtain a lock and locks a set of rows
   - Thread 2, tries to obtain the lock on the same set of rows (as were locked by Thread 1) at this time thread 2 gets a exception saying that Rows are locked

   Which would be the best pessimistic LockMode?

Comment: Is this your todays homework?

Comment: No bish, handling a business use case. :)

Answer (score 6):

1. The [LockMode.UPGRADE](http://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-java-persistence-locking/) uses `select ... for update`, so the locks are held for [the whole duration of the current transaction](http://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-locking-patterns-how-do-pessimistic_read-and-pessimistic_write-work/). The only way to release the locks is to either commit or rollback the transaction.
2. A `select ... for update` lock will cause the second transaction to wait for the first one to release the locks. If you want to fail fast, you need to use: [UPGRADE_NOWAIT](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/LockMode.html#UPGRADE_NOWAIT), which will use `select ... for update no wait` query, that throws an exception if the lock cannot be acquired (this is supported by Oracle and PostgreSQL).
3. Or, you can use the Hibernate `LockOptions` as follows:

   ```
   entityManager
   .unwrap(Session.class)
   .buildLockRequest(
       new LockOptions(LockMode.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
       .setTimeOut(LockOptions.NO_WAIT))
   .lock(entity);
   ```

For more details, check out my [Transactions and Concurrency Control presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=onYjxRcToto) from Voxxed Days Zurich.

Comment: Thanks Vlad, was trying to implement a Pessimistic lock with no wait condition in MySQL but does not seem possible. Will have to go with optimistic version check strategy.